# How to pass ["Some Info 1","Some Info 2"] in Flutter Http package

Tags: flutter, http

I'm developing an app which required api call to our server. I have to pass List as Parameter but when I try to pass List it go as String like "["Some Info 1","Some Info 2"]". I have try to debug and and when it's doing http request it's automatically add "" surround list.

This my Service Class

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> post(
  String _url, Map<String, String> _headers, Map<String, String> _params) {
print('_url => $_url');
if (_headers != null) {
  print('_headers => $_headers');
}
print('_params => $_params');
return http
    .post(Uri.parse(BASE_URL + _url),
        headers: (_headers != null) ? _headers : {}, body: _params)
    .then(
  (response) {
    final code = response.statusCode;
    final body = response.body;
    final jsonBody = json.decode(body);
    debugPrint('response code => $code');
    debugPrint('response body => $body');

    Map<String, dynamic> _resDic;
    if (code == 200 || code == 300) {
      _resDic = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonBody);
      _resDic[HTTP_CODE] = code;
      print('Success => ${_resDic[HTTP_CODE]}');
      if (code == 422) {
        SharedPref.saveString(AUTH_TOKEN, '');
        SharedPref.saveInt(USER_TYPE, 0);
        SharedPref.saveObject(USER, null);
        SharedPref.resetData();
        navigationKey.currentState
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(LOGIN, (route) => false);

        if (_resDic[IS_TOKEN_EXPIRED] == 1) {
          _resDic[HTTP_CODE] = 422;
        }
      }
    } else {
      _resDic = Map<String, dynamic>();
      _resDic[HTTP_CODE] = code;
      _resDic[IS_TOKEN_EXPIRED] = 0;
      _resDic[MESSAGE] = jsonBody[MESSAGE] != null
          ? jsonBody[MESSAGE]
          : 'Something went wrong';
      _resDic[HTTP_CODE] = code;
    }
    print('===>> Response : $_resDic');
    return _resDic;
  },
);
```

}

Comment: encode your params like `jsonEncode(_params)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this way.

```
 generateHeaders() async {
    String _token = await SharedPref.readString(AUTH_TOKEN);
    return {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $_token',
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };
  }

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postDynamic(
      String _url, Map<String, String> _headers, Map<String, dynamic> _params) {
    print('_url => $_url');
    if (_headers != null) {
      print('_headers => $_headers');
    }
    print('_params => $_params');
    return http
        .post(Uri.parse(BASE_URL + _url),
            headers: (_headers != null) ? _headers : {},
            body: json.encode(_params))
        .then(
      (response) {
        final code = response.statusCode;
        final body = response.body;
        final jsonBody = json.decode(body);
        debugPrint('response code => $code');
        debugPrint('response body => $body');
        print('response code => $code');
        Map<String, dynamic> _resDic;
        if (code == 200 || code == 300) {
          _resDic = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonBody);
          _resDic[HTTP_CODE] = code;
          print('Success => ${_resDic[HTTP_CODE]}');
        } else if (code == 401) {
          SharedPref.saveString(AUTH_TOKEN, '');
          SharedPref.saveInt(USER_TYPE, 0);
          SharedPref.saveObject(USER, null);
          SharedPref.resetData();
          navigationKey.currentState
              .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(LOGIN, (route) => false);
        } else {
          _resDic = Map<String, dynamic>();
          _resDic[HTTP_CODE] = code;
          _resDic[IS_TOKEN_EXPIRED] = 0;
          _resDic[MESSAGE] = jsonBody[MESSAGE] != null
              ? jsonBody[MESSAGE]
              : 'Something went wrong';
          _resDic[HTTP_CODE] = code;
        }
        print('===>> Response : $_resDic');
        return _resDic;
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode your params with

```
json.encode(params)
```